# Why is a syncdb not populating models.py models?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-admin

I have, in models.py:

```
class Flashcard(models.Model):
    english = models.TextField()
    slavonic = models.TextField()
```

urls.py references models.py in an attempt to make python manage.py syncdb pick up on models.py:

```
import models
```

However, a python manage.py syncdb does not result in the creation of a `*_flashcards` table:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb && sqlite3 flashcards.db 
No fixtures found.
SQLite version 3.7.13 2012-06-11 02:05:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
auth_group                  auth_user_user_permissions
auth_group_permissions      django_admin_log          
auth_message                django_content_type       
auth_permission             django_session            
auth_user                   django_site               
auth_user_groups          
sqlite>
```

What should I be doing differently to get a `flashcards_flashcards` table? The admin interface picks up on it perfectly, up to displaying an "Add entry" page for the model.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add your app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings file, that's why `syncdb` command is not picking the models defined in that app.